# How to put a full stop at the bottom, not mid-line, after an aligned matrix?

Tags: amsmath, matrices, punctuation

How can I put a full stop at the bottom rather than at mid-line following the end of an aligned matrix expression such as `$\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}$`?

Comment: Probably you know it but did you try the `smallmatrix` environment already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a stop with a second matrix (sans brackets) and phantom elements. The result is that the full stop is aligned as if next to bottom element in the matrix.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}\begin{matrix} \vphantom{x}\\ \vphantom{y}.\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The stop may look misaligned, but see the image below. The downside is that you have to include this phantom matrix, but it does work.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Something like `\raisebox{\depth}{$\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}$}.` works.  However, this is probably not a good idea from the typographic point of view: imagine the equation `A=\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}`.  Where would you put the full stop?  I think the current default where `matrix` has nonzero depth (i.e. extends below the baseline) is right.

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
  \raisebox{\depth}{$\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}$}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this. But having lowered the full stop that way, I've then caused two more problems, posted here at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/how-to-position-mid-line-inside-a-raisebox-and-then-align-using-wi