# How to position "=" mid-line inside a '\raisebox' and then `align` using `&=` with expression below?

Tags: align, matrices

In order to get a full stop at the bottom, rather than mid-line, after an aligned matrix expression, I have raised the expression using a raisebox, and adjusted space using `vspace'. This is now causing further problems. The expression contains an "=", but this is now going to the bottom rather than staying mid-line. How do I keep it mid-line? Also, how do I now align the expression with an expression below which is not in a raisebox?

It might be easiest if I show what I had before using the raisebox. I want to keep this the same, except with the full stop at the bottom:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} a\\b \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} c\\d \end{pmatrix}.\\
\intertext{Now}
\begin{pmatrix} e\\f \end{pmatrix}&= \begin{pmatrix} g\\h \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
```

I can raise the full stop using:

```
\begin{align}
\raisebox{\depth}{$\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix} a\\b \end{pmatrix} \displaystyle\begin{pmatrix} c\\d \end{pmatrix}$}\\
\end{align}
```

but this causes the problems mentioned above. Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: That's why it's a bad idea to put the period at the bottom of the matrix: it should be at a position compatible with the `=`. So usually people consider matrices just like fractions: half above the baseline and half below it (almost).

Comment: Hmm - I'll have to think about whether leaving `.` mid-line, level with `=`, will be OK. At the moment, the difference with their relative positions when matrices or fractions are inline, when  `=` is higher than `.`, is looking a bit odd to me.

Comment: it's "standard" (or at least "house style") for most math publishers to consider the baseline with the `=` to be the one on which the period should be located.  as for relative positioning of those two glyphs, the `=` is aligned vertically on the math axis, while the period sits on the actual baseline.  a dot centered on the math axis would not be a period, but a `\cdot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the dot in the sub-script, and then modify the font size and the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

 % This prints a dot, slightly moved closer to the parenthesis and at the correct size.
\def\FullStop{{\kern-0.5ex\raise0.3ex\hbox{\normalsize.}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 % You can place the full stop as a sub-script of the matrix.
\begin{pmatrix} a\\b \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} c\\d \end{pmatrix}_\FullStop\\
\intertext{Now}
\begin{pmatrix} e\\f \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} g\\h \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```