# How to put a period after a matrix

Tags: math-mode, positioning, matrices, punctuation

How to put a period after a matrix (and not have it float in the air). For example, consider the following matrix:

```
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.
```

You find the period floats in the middle of the line rather than sinking to the bottom. How to make it appear properly at the bottom.

Comment: The `.` is at the bottom if you have  an inline math mode, but the matrix is 'centered' vertically (stated better: raised down), e.g. try `A is matrix like $\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.` and you will see that `.` is on the baseline

Comment: @Hao Sun, can you take a look at the first related question on the right side http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41783/2288 ? answers there may give what you want.

Answer (score 6):

In inline math, the `.` is set on the baseline. In display math, the `.` is set on the baseline of the vertical center of the formula (since the matrix is vertically centered).

However odd it may seem, you can use the fact that `bmatrix` sets `\left`/`\right` delimiters to place the `.` at the lower-right as a "limit":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

Here we have $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix}$. And there is also
\[
  B = \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y
  \end{bmatrix}.
\]

Here we have $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. And there is also
\[
  B = \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y \\
    1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}.
\]

\hrulefill

Here we have $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}_{\textstyle .}$ or 
             $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}_{\textstyle \raisebox{2pt}{.}}$ or
             $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 1 & 2\rlap{~.}\end{bmatrix}$~
And there is also
\[
  B = \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y \\
    1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}_{\textstyle .} \quad
  B = \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y \\
    1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}_{\textstyle \raisebox{2pt}{.}}\quad
  B = \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y \\
    1 & 2\rlap{~.}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Personally I'd stick with the default placement.

Comment: The duplicate question does not have your solution of placing the period with a subscript. I'd recommend adding this answer in the "duplicate" question.